# Smooth scrolling workaround

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, smooth-scrolling

I’m working with nav bar that becomes fixed at max-width 1000px. The height is 60px.

My problem is page jump will not reach the place it should.

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        if (target.length <= 1000) {
          $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top - 60
          }, 1000);
        };
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? What is your specific problem and what is the expected result? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It might be worth checking out Penner's Easing Functions. They're smooth, simple and deterministic.

Comment: My question is how can I make the the scrolling reach the place it should kinda media query but for JS.

Comment: By the way thanks for fixing my post!

Comment: Once you detect the animation has finished, why don't you manually set the position to the setpoint to prevent any overlap? You might have cases where `target.length` has exceeded 1000, but you stop checking from there. A lot of this logic is kind of application specific, you should try giving us a working example.

Comment: with this code it will be up 60px of the place it should be while is not fixed meaning when the screen have less than 1000px.

Comment: This should do the trick : http://pastebin.com/R5aAXBJJ.

Comment: @AlexT.  thanks! I will read the Penner's functions since I haven't

Comment: I think `target.length` is misunderstood... it's not a scroll position on the page but checks if there are any elements inside the object - so basically if an anchor target exists or not.

Comment: @Shikkediel for some reason is not working as I need.

Comment: Maybe you could add the HTML or a live link then.

Comment: @Shikkediel  It surely fix it when the nav is fixed but when is not I have 60px up that is my original problem.

Comment: I suspect it has to do with the fact that the header takes up space when it's not fixed. Otherwise it is taken out of document flow which influences the offset of the elements. The simplest approach would probably be to give the previous element `margin-bottom: 60px` when the header switches to fixed position. And remove it vice versa. Then the function in the link should work as expected.

Comment: @Shikkediel  thanks! finally did it here's the code in the end it was really straight fordward

Comment: Cheers, I totally misread it was about the page's *width* myself...

Comment: @Shikkediel Thanks! it feels good to fix something in a language that I'm not an expert at all, even if it really was straightforward. And thanks for your help you guide me here. Also it's a shame that I was negatively voted, well anyway I will leave this here maybe it will help somebody.

Comment: @Whitehawk If you have found the solution please post it and accept it as the correct answer so it closes the question :)

Comment: @Canvas Thanks I didn't know, now it's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did it! this will go backwards 60px with a max-width screen of 1000px

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        if (matchMedia('only screen and (max-width: 1000px)').matches) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top -60
        }, 1000);

        return false;
      }
    }}
  });
});
```